# Save exported csv to a location on app storage

Tags: php, laravel, csv, storage

I am trying to save some failed records as csv to my laravel app storage. I have gone through this [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) but how to store the file in a desired location is my challenge.

```js
$failedRecordArrayFile = arrayToCsv($failedRecordArray, "file101.csv");


function arrayToCsv($data, $fileName)
{
    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

I ran the code block above and checked for  the file name "file101.csv" in my entire application but I couldn't find any result.

Comment: Have you tried to pass an absolute path to `fopen`?

Comment: hi, please see below a proposed answer... for one the function may need to be on top ... cheers

Comment: @Ruperto the function is actually  called from a helper class. That shouldn't be issue

Comment: i see. i would perhaps try  storage_path()

Comment: I don't understand please what you mean by storage_path()

Comment: storage_path() returns the storage folder i.e. usually c:\...\laravel\storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would work...

```
<?php 

function arrayToCsv($data, $fileName)
{
    $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');

    foreach ($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

$failedRecordArray = array(array('col1','col2','col3','col4'), array('This','is','a','test'));
$failedRecordArrayFile = arrayToCsv($failedRecordArray, "file101.csv");
?>
```

file101.csv

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
This,is,a,test
```

Comment: where (location) will the file be stored please. I am using laravel